# Receiving packets for different MAC address

Tags: c, windows, networking, packet-capture, winpcap

is it possible to capture some packets in promiscuous mode (e.g. using winpcap) and than force OS (applications) to receive them as they were sent for our MAC?

My observation is following. We can:

- capture all network traffic using
  promiscuous mode (winpcap)
- filter/modify the packets using
  firewall-hook/filter-hook
- send packets to the network with altered MAC

I am not sure if firewall-hook can access all the packets which are available thanks to promiscious mode. Isn't it on the lower layer? If it can't, the only solution would be to capture desired packets and then resend them to the network with altered MAC?

I am networking novice so please be easy on me :)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have your toes at the line of white hat/black hat hackers.  I know that my company actively watches for promiscuous NICs, hunts down the owners and kills (fires) them.  Maybe if you ask us what you're trying to do, we can offer some suggestions.

If you're trying to analyze your network, there is software and/or hardware solutions that will probably do a better job.  If you're just trying to watch interesting text flow across your network, well ... maybe you're still in college.

Comment: All I want to do is to have 2 MAC/IP addresses on a single NIC. Unfortunatelly the NIC does not support this feature, but I am sure there are workarounds ... and ofcoarse I am curious :)

Comment: @Petr Why would you *need* two MAC addresses? It's perfectlyvalid for a single NIC, with a single MAC address to have many IP addresses

Comment: @Rowland Yes, but it still looks like one device for other peers. I would like to simulate two separate devices from a single one.

Comment: All I can suggest is to try HyperV or a similar VM environment that will virtualize a network through your single NIC.  I know that I type in the MAC address and that's what gets reported to the world.

Answer (score 1):

First, yes if your interface operates in promiscuous mode then you will receive everything 'on the wire'. Which is already one difficulty, nowadays many (if not all) networks are switched, which means a piece of hardware exterior to your system will already do some filtering before packets arrive at your system, so you'll first need to trick a switch into transmitting those packets to your end (can be done by sending out dummy arps, by configuring the switch, or by bad intent ;-) ). 
Then if these packets receive at your system, what do you plan to do with them ? There ethernet frames will carry ip packets, typically with a destination ip address, which is already something which will not be on your host (and if it is, this implies that you will have duplicate ip addresses on your network, causing problems as well.

So the main question is, what do you really really really want to do ?

Comment: Thanks fot the answer. I have no problems with promiscious mode (already tested with Wireshark). The trick is that the packets will actully be responses for my requests (sent with my "virtual" MAC). I plan to make a tool which would allow different applictions to communicate with network both using different MAC/IP addresses simultaneously.

Comment: Then why do you still need al this rewriting etc ? Or why don't you simply use your native mac address and do your filtering on ip level ?

Comment: Because this way, with two MAC addresses I could use two different internet connections and combine their bandwidth :) ... I can act as two peers => I have doubled bandwidth.

Comment: +1 very good point about switches. This is precisely why I keep around an old dumb hub for when I need to do sniffing on a link.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have recieved a packet, it has already been clean through the protocol stack. I don't think Windows gives you the access into the middle of Winsock that would be required to somehow stick it back in.

More importantly, this is a really dodgy think to be looking to do. Whatever it is you are looking to do, I can guarantee you there is some better way to do it.

Comment: It's why I have to use firewall-hook driver isn't it? I know there is better way - to buy a hardware which will support this, but I would like to do that software way.